# How to fix Unable to execute action botFramework/create. Error message: API call to Developer Portal failed

Tags: azure-bot-service, teams-toolkit

I am trying to create a simple test chatbot using Microsoft Teams Toolkit.

I don't have permissions to perform action:

botAadApp/create

So, I asked the admin to create me an azure bot, so I am using the bot id and password, filling in env.local and env.local.user files respectively.

When I run Debug in teams (Edge) I got the following error:

2024-03-18T16:01:27.760Z] [Error] - Unable to execute action botFramework/create. Error message: API call to Developer Portal failed. Check Output panel for details.

[2024-03-18T16:01:27.761Z] [Error] - Failed to Execute lifecycle provision due to failed action: botFramework/create. DeveloperPortalAPIFailedError:API call to Developer Portal failed: AxiosError, Request failed with status code 400, API name: create-bot, X-Correlation-ID: da4247d6-190d-445a-a624-2d3d910f7091. This may come from some intermittent service error. Please wait for a few minutes and retry the current step. data: "The Microsoft App ID is already registered to another bot application.". Env output: {"TEAMS_APP_ID":"**","TEAMS_APP_TENANT_ID":"**","BOT_ID":"**","SECRET_BOT_PASSWORD":"******"}

[2024-03-18T16:01:27.762Z] [Info] - Execution summary:

Summary:

(×) Error: Lifecycle stage provision failed.

(√) Done: teamsApp/create was executed successfully.

```
(√) Done: Teams app with id *** already exists, skipped creating a new Teams app.
```

(√) Done: botAadApp/create was executed successfully.

```
(√) Done: Used existing Microsoft Entra application with client id 1294e29c-cc99-4ac5-adb8-a3c8145a64e7.
```

(×) Error: botFramework/create failed.

```
(×) Error: API call to Developer Portal failed: AxiosError, Request failed with status code 400, API name: create-bot, X-Correlation-ID: da4247d6-190d-445a-a624-2d3d910f7091. This may come from some intermittent service error. Please wait for a few minutes and retry the current step. data: "The Microsoft App ID is already registered to another bot application."
```

(!) Warning: teamsApp/validateManifest was not executed.

(!) Warning: teamsApp/zipAppPackage was not executed.

(!) Warning: teamsApp/validateAppPackage was not executed.

(!) Warning: teamsApp/update was not executed.

[2024-03-18T16:01:28.086Z] [Error] - code:AppStudioPlugin.DeveloperPortalAPIFailedError, message: API call to Developer Portal failed: AxiosError, Request failed with status code 400, API name: create-bot, X-Correlation-ID: da4247d6-190d-445a-a624-2d3d910f7091. This may come from some intermittent service error. Please wait for a few minutes and retry the current step. data: "The Microsoft App ID is already registered to another bot application." Alternatively, you can bypass this step by selecting the 'Debug in Test Tool' option.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue as https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/issues/11100. Please check it.